# Drag circles with scaleLinear initial position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm having trouble dragging circles within my chart. Here is the live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/71loxoq65j.

My chart

```
import { event, select, Selection } from "d3-selection";
import { scaleLinear, ScaleLinear } from "d3-scale";
import { Axis, axisBottom, axisLeft } from "d3-axis";
import { line, Line } from "d3-shape";
import { drag } from "d3-drag";

interface IMargin {
  left: number;
  right: number;
  top: number;
  bottom: number;
}

interface IConfig {
  height: number;
  margin: IMargin;
  target: SVGSVGElement;
  width: number;
}

interface ISample {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

export default class Trigger {
  private chart: Selection<SVGGElement, {}, null, undefined>;
  private xScale: ScaleLinear<number, number>;
  private yScale: ScaleLinear<number, number>;
  private xAxis: Axis<number>;
  private xAxisGroup: Selection<SVGGElement, {}, null, undefined>;
  private yAxis: Axis<number>;
  private yAxisGroup: Selection<SVGGElement, {}, null, undefined>;

  constructor(config: IConfig) {
    const w = config.width - config.margin.left - config.margin.right;
    const h = config.height - config.margin.top - config.margin.bottom;

    // create global chart object
    this.chart = select(config.target)
      .attr("width", config.width)
      .attr("height", config.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        `translate(${config.margin.left}, ${config.margin.top})`
      );

    // create x scale function
    this.xScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, w]);

    // create y scale function
    this.yScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([h, 0]);

    // create x axis function
    this.xAxis = (axisBottom(this.xScale) as Axis<number>).ticks(5);

    // create y axis function
    this.yAxis = (axisLeft(this.yScale) as Axis<number>).ticks(5);

    // append x axis to chart and call xAxis function
    this.xAxisGroup = this.chart
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${h})`)
      .call(this.xAxis);

    // append y axis to chart and call yAxis function
    this.yAxisGroup = this.chart
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(this.yAxis);

    // add x axis description
    this.chart
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", w / 2)
      .attr("y", h + config.margin.bottom)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("foo");

    // add y axis description
    this.chart
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", -h / 2)
      .attr("y", -config.margin.left)
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
      .text("bar");
  }

  public yellow(data: ISample[]) {
    // draw circles
    this.chart
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => this.xScale(d.x))
      .attr("cy", d => this.yScale(d.y))
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .call(
        drag().on("drag", function(d) {
          select(this).attr("cx", (d.x = event.x));
        })
      );
  }
}
```

And my component which is calling the chart

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Chart from "./chart";

import "./styles.css";

const Trigger = () => {
  const chart: React.MutableRefObject<Chart | null> = React.useRef(null);

  const chartRef = React.useRef(null);

  const [start, setStart] = React.useState(20);
  const [end, setEnd] = React.useState(50);

  // run on did mount but never again
  React.useEffect(() => {
    chart.current = new Chart({
      height: 320,
      margin: {
        bottom: 40,
        left: 50,
        right: 20,
        top: 10
      },
      target: chartRef.current!,
      width: 640
    });

    const yellow = [{ x: start, y: 50 }, { x: end, y: 50 }];
    chart.current.yellow(yellow);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={chartRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Trigger />, rootElement);
```

As you can see the initial position on the first drag is wrong. It always starts at `0`. The circle jumps to the left. Afterwards everything is fine and it works as expected. I tried to follow this simple example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e but it doesn't have any scales.

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Mirco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the mouse position to the `g` of the chart

```
import { event, select, Selection, mouse } from "d3-selection";


  public yellow(data: ISample[]) {
    // draw circles
    var that = this;
    this.chart
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => this.xScale(d.x))
      .attr("cy", d => this.yScale(d.y))
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", "orange")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .call(
        drag().on("drag", function(d) {
          select(this).attr("cx", (d.x = mouse(that.chart.node())[0]));
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: You brought me on the right track. Here is my solution.

        `drag().on('drag', (d: ISample, i: number, group) => {
          const element = group[i];
          const coordinates = mouse(element);
          const x = coordinates[0];
          d.x = this.xScale.invert(x);
          select(element).attr('cx', x);
        })`